# How to retrieve the Hugo winners from Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am new to SPARQL and Wikidata, and am trying to retrieve the following for the Hugo Award Winners:

- Work Title
- Author
- Year Won

I'm finding this surprisingly difficult.

I started off querying for all tuples linking to the award for best novel with a link type of "won by".

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?winner WHERE {
  # P166: Award Recieved By
  # Q103360: Hugo Award for Best Novel
  ?winner ps:P1346 wd:Q255032.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

This works, but when I add the title link from the winner, there's no data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?winner WHERE {
  ?winner ps:P1346 wd:Q255032.

  OPTIONAL {
    # P1476: Title
    ?winner wdt:P1476 ?title.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried different namespaces, with little comprehension, and to no avail.

On the page for the Hugo winners, there's a section of winners: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q255032#P1346

How is that generated? I tried to query that property and got back links to people (I think):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?winner ?winnerLabel ?for WHERE {
  # P166: winner
  # Q103360: Hugo Award for Best Novel
  wd:Q255032 wdt:P1346 ?winner.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Comment: Your first query does **not** return anything! At least not for me right now when I tried it on https://query.wikidata.org. So why are you not using `wdt:P166` as predicate?

Comment: And the second query also works when you use the predicate `wdt:P166`. But, to get the fields back have to have to add them to the SELECT part of course, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT ?winner ?winnerLabel ?titleLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For predicate you should use `wdt:` instead `ps:`

Please look at [this example](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FAuthorLabel%20%3Fyear%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20wd%3AQ255032.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP50%20%3FAuthor%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fyear%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?AuthorLabel ?year WHERE {  
  ?item wdt:P166 wd:Q255032.
  ?item wdt:P50 ?Author .  
  ?item wdt:P577 ?year .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }    
}
```

PS. I used publication, not winning date.

**UPDATE**: Please see [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10640/3286):

> The point in time property of the award received is what Wikidata
>   calls a qualifier.

And [this is query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FauthorLabel%20%3FpublicationDate%20%3FdateOfAwardReceived%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP50%20%3Fauthor%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP577%20%3FpublicationDate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP166%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20ps%3AP166%20wd%3AQ255032%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20pq%3AP585%20%3FdateOfAwardReceived%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?authorLabel ?publicationDate ?dateOfAwardReceived WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P50 ?author .  
  ?item wdt:P577 ?publicationDate .
  ?item p:P166 ?awardReceivedStatement .
  ?awardReceivedStatement ps:P166 wd:Q255032 .
  ?awardReceivedStatement pq:P585 ?dateOfAwardReceived .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }    
}
```

Comment: I really need the year the award was given. Is that easily possible?

Comment: @Will, a little bit more complex, I'll try

Comment: The program I'm working on (https://github.com/dhappy/awards/blob/master/test.rb) is creating a tree of symlinks of the form /award/Hugo/#{year} → /book/by/#{author}/#{title}. I'm getting 13 collisions currently on years.

Comment: @Will, it's easy to get direct properties, like Author or publication year, but award year is not direct, it's award received -> point in time, I'm sure it's possible to get it, just not sure how yet.

Comment: @Will, I asked this question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/wikidata-get-property-of-property

Comment: That really helped out. I ended up with: https://github.com/dhappy/awards/blob/f3aa10843b2bc410900d0e58e6965c6cba746451/test.rb#L35-L40 I'm still getting four collisions, but I'm pretty sure the data's off.